# Quantiles of a data.frame

Tags: r, quantile

There is a data.frame() for which's columns I'd like to calculate quantiles:

```
tert <- c(0:3)/3
data <- dbGetQuery(dbCon, "SELECT * FROM tablename")
quans <- mapply(quantile, data, probs=tert, name=FALSE)
```

But the result only contains the last element of quantiles return list and not the whole result. I also get a warning `longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter`. How can I modify my code to make it work?

PS: The function alone works like a charme, so I *could* use a for loop:

```
quans <- quantile(a$fileName, probs=tert, name=FALSE)
```

PPS: What also works is *not* specifying `probs`

```
quans <- mapply(quantile, data, name=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `mapply` is trying to apply the given function to each of the elements of *all* of the specified arguments in sequence. Since you only want to do this for one argument, you should use `lapply`, not `mapply`:

```
lapply(data, quantile, probs=tert, name=FALSE)
```

Alternatively, you can still use `mapply` but specify the arguments that are *not* to be looped over in the `MoreArgs` argument.

```
mapply(quantile, data, MoreArgs=list(probs=tert, name=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a *workaround* which I don't like but kinda works. Perhaps someone can tell the *right* way to do it:

```
q <- function(x) { quantile(x, probs=c(0:3)/3, names=FALSE) }
mapply(q, data)
```

works, no Idea where the difference is.